# Is it possible to create a nested table in SQLite

Tags: sql

I've got basic knowledge of SQL, knowing only how to create and insert data intoa table. I'm currently trying to created a database with SQLite, where one column would have sort of a nested table. Is this possible with SQLite ?

[image: tabe description]

Comment: I don't think it's possible in SQLite or any traditional SQL DB. You may want to consider normalizing your data model.

Comment: Why would you want to? Just build normal related tables. Closest to what you describe is multi-value field in Access database. And I do not recommend that field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [lokijs](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS), a super fast in-memory javascript document oriented database

Comment: you should really read into data modeling, those nested-tables idea is the wrong approach. what you want is simply a second table connected to the first one through a foreign key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).